# Accessing model property that has the InverseProperty annotation result in NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

NOTE: I do get a valid result from the .Find(id) 'query'. The NullReferenceException is thrown when I access the "Posts" field.

I have the 2 model classes "Post" and "Thread":

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Thread Thread { get; set; }
}

public class Thread
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }         
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Section Section { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Thread")]
    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

From what I understand, I should be able to get all Post entries that links to a Thread by accessing the property "Posts".

Using the following code I try to access the property:

```
using (var dbcontext = new DataBaseContext()) // I get a connection to the database
{
    Thread thread = dbcontext.Thread.Find(id); // I get a row from the table

    foreach(var post in thread.Posts) // It's *here* that the exception is thrown
    {
        // do something with that data
    }                    
}
```

The result is that I get a NullReferenceException. I thought that accessing the Posts property, that is initially null since it's not in the database, would result in a lazy load (since it has the InverseProperty annotation).

Comment: You are making a lot of assumptions like you are connected to the database.  Is the object dbcontext null? Does the object contain your tables?

Comment: If the problem was the dbcontext, I would have said so. It's the Posts property that is null in the Thread class (the others match the database), and there is no lazy load when I try to access it.

Comment: Check the model to make sure the two tables are linked by Id.

Comment: I generated the tables using migration from the source code. There are foreign keys for the columns (I checked INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE). I did save a 'Post' earlier using the dbcontext, but for some reason it looks like Thread/User is null when retrieved (not null in the database)

Comment: Usually this occurs when Id is a string in one place and an integer in another place.  Is the variable id declared as a string or integer?